# NoneType' object has no attribute 'items

Tags: python, nonetype

I don't really know where I went wrong. Can you please help me? I keep getting this error when uploading the code to school correction system.

```
  -- test: 1
  -- failed

  -- standard error
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/proc/self/fd/3", line 6, in <module>
      print(sorted(new_dict.items()))
  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items'
  --
  -- exit code: 1
                (anything other than 0 indicates an error)
                (all scripts are killed after three seconds)

  -- expected standard output
  [(4, 'a'), (10, 'c')]
  --

  -- actual standard output (max 200 lines)
  [(4, 'a'), (10, 'c')]
  --
```

My code is:

```
import sys

def swap_unique_keys_values(n):
    d = {}
    for i in n:
        if not n[i] in d:
            d[n[i]] = i
        else:
            del d[n[i]]
    print(sorted(d.items()))

def main():
    swap_unique_keys_values(sys.argv[1])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The input is a dictionary. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: The traceback doesn't match your code.

Answer (score 1):

That error almost always means that you forgot to return a value from a method.

Some other method called your method, saved the returned value, and then tried to operate on it. Python said, "nope, there's no value there, it's just None"

Try returning a value in `swap_unique_keys`

Comment: When I try to return a value it fixes the error, but when i try to return sorted(d.items()) it says list object has no attribute items

Comment: Unfortunately, then, I think that's part of the homework assignment! Good luck :)

Comment: It is not an assignment, the teacher gave us this task to try it and I could use some help to fix the error

Comment: Ok, you have enough information, but I'll help you see what you're missing.
What datatypes have a method items()? That's probably the type you want to be returning from that method.